# USB Keyboard and Mouse are not working in Windows but works in BIOS

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers, keyboard, mouse

I have deleted some services and drivers from ASUS and after that my USB peripherals are not working.

Call me stupid. I can take it .

Keyboard and mouse are working in recovery mode and BIOS but turning off in Windows.

I have tried recovery but nothing helps. Is there any possibilities to fix that without deleting windows? Thank you.

Windows 8.1

Razer Deathadder elite and Ornata

ASUS Z170-P

Comment: That is a serious case. You most likely removed the chipset drivers which has USB support, and caused all your usb devices to stop working. That would mean your keyboard and mouse drivers still work, but they can't be used. You can see if you can restore to an earlier restore point, or see if you can connect to the pc remotely, which should mean you can still use the mouse, then fix the issue.

Comment: There is no possibility to go back to restore point. Because I don't have any of them. Also I can't connect to PC remotely. My Wi-Fi USB module is not working too.

Comment: Can you connect using a network cable?

Comment: I mean, the alternative is a windows reinstall...

Comment: I think I can. But IDK is remote control is available.

Comment: Can I update my windows from 8.1 to 10 without disk format?

Comment: Yes, and that could fix your issue. But if you then go back to 8.1, so will your problem.

Comment: Remote control is not possible. So the only way to fix is reinstall windows? I have cmd in recovery mode. Can it help me somehow?

Comment: It could, but is very tricky. You could use it to install software such as teamviewer so remote control becomes possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your ASUS Z170P mobo has two old-style PCI slots. Get an old-style EHCI PCI host controller, the system might find right default driver for it. Or auto-install the EHCI driver from accompanying CD (if autoplay is enabled).

Your mobo also has PS/2 ports for keyboard/mouse. Go to a junk electronic store and get PS/2 devices. Then re-install USB drivers from ASUS website using CD/DVD.